# Large TTFB on Vagrant

Tags: performance, vagrant

I have a ttfb of approximately 15-20 seconds on a [VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) vagrant install. I am using virtual box on windows 7 in case that makes any difference.

I have tried reprovisioning and also tried increasing the memory to 2040MB. What other things can I try and what are some likely causes?

Comment: You're using both VirtualBox and Windows 7. You should not expect high performance.

Comment: I would have thought I could expect a ttfb of less than 15 seconds, no?

Comment: Not necessarily. VirtualBox is not a production quality hypervisor and Windows 7 is not a server platform.

Comment: I think people use virtualbox on windows regularly for development - I doubt anyone would be able to be productive at those speeds. I'd say much faster speeds have to be possible somehow